# How to use parallelization with raster::extract in R using furrr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, raster, furrr

I am unsure if this is a bug or a how-to. I posted this question [here](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/299) and was told to ask StackOverflow!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(elevatr)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(furrr)

multco <- tigris::tracts(state = "OR", 
    county = "Multnomah") %>% 
  st_transform(2913) %>% 
  st_point_on_surface()

ex_elev <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(
    locations = st_bbox(multco) %>% st_as_sfc(), 
    z = 5)

# This works
ev <- raster::extract(ex_elev, multco, 
    fun = mean, na.rm = T, buffer = 100)

## This fails
ev2 <- multco %>% 
  furrr::future_map_dbl(.f = function(point){
    raster::extract(ex_elev, point, fun = mean, na.rm = T, buffer = 100)}, 
             .options = furrr_options(seed = TRUE,
                                      packages = c("raster", "sf")))
```

with the following error code:
`Error in round(y) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

It works with serial processing however.

I'm not sure if it's a `{raster}` issue or a `{future}` issue or a `{furrr}` issue. If anyone has luck using furrr-based parallelization and mapping with `{raster}` functions, please let me know!

**Edit 1**: Changed code to fully reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried to add **raster** to manually attached packages, i.e. `furrr_options(packages = ("raster", "sf"))`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example where you show what packages to attach. If I try with `purrr::map()`, I get error "mydat %>% purrr::map(.f = ~raster::extract(elev_terrain, .x, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE, buffer = 200))
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extract': object 'elev_terrain' not found".

Comment: @HenrikB, my apologies for not having a fully reproducible example. I forgot to include the elevation raster image. I have updated my question to include a different, reproduciple example. Also tried adding the packages. Different error code now!

Comment: Sorry, still not reproducible. Missing several `library()` calls, e.g. I know I need `library(magrittr)`, but there are more missing.  Please make sure you try your own code starting out in a fresh R session with no packages loaded.

Comment: @HenrikB I added the library calls necessary. (I didn't realize it was necessary when I specify the namespace with `package::function()` format.)

Comment: It wasn't that. It was that also called functions and infix operators that were imported.  Again, e.g., if you start a fresh R session, then `%>%` is undefined.  Your code use `%>%`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will in the future. (For now `library(tidyverse)` will handle the pipe infix operator.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, rarely parallel extraction is needed. Often the overheads to pass the data to the workers are more expensive than computing the extraction in sequential mode. However, `purrr::map` and their parallel version use a list as an argument, so you have to convert your `sf` to a list. See my example with a little time benchmark of different approaches:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(elevatr)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(furrr)


# This works
system.time(ev <- raster::extract(ex_elev, multco, 
                     fun = mean, na.rm = T, buffer = 100))#51.84

system.time(ev <- terra::extract(ex_elev, multco, 
                      fun = mean, na.rm = T, buffer = 100))#57.2

system.time(ev <- exactextractr::exact_extract(ex_elev, st_buffer(multco,100), 
                      "mean"))#0.43



#in parallel
xy.list <- split(multco, seq(nrow(multco)))

plan(multisession)

system.time(ev2 <- xy.list %>% 
  furrr::future_map_dbl(.f = function(point){
    raster::extract(ex_elev, point, fun = mean, na.rm = T, buffer = 100)}, 
    .options = furrr_options(seed = TRUE,
                             packages = c("raster", "sf")))
)#208
plan(sequential)
```

in the comment of each approach, you will see the elapsed time (in seconds) on my machine (64 Gb RAM and 48 logical cores). As you can see, with your toy data, the `exact_extract` approach is by far the better

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that parallelization had an additional cost that exceeds the point of it.